# Inline edit not working in grid

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, ui-grid

I have created a inline edit for a grid. The inline editing is working fine when there is a single row. But if there are more then I'm not able to edit the values and save them.

Here is my code.

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
</listingToolbar>


<columns name="spinner_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">bom_order_edit.bom_order_edit.spinner_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
                <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="bom/asyn/edititem"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">bom_order_edit.bom_order_edit.spinner_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">order_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="order_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="vendor_id" class="Jon\Bom\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\VendorName">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Vendor Name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="type" class="Jon\Bom\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ProductType">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Type</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="unit">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unit</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>


    <column name="qty">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-zero-or-greater" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>

            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

</columns>
```

Here is what I'm getting.
[image]

It's showing two selected but actually its only one I clicked, Even I cannot edit those value and save them.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why your rows are duplicate?
it edits two because it get same id for two rows

Comment: Ya you are right. How did i missed that one. Thank you